# Why are these two samples correlated with each other (ISLR package)?

Tags: r, self-study, correlation, random-variable

On pg. 44 of *Introduction to Statistical Learning*:

> Here we create two correlated sets of numbers, `x` and `y`, and use
>   the `cor()` function to compute the correlation between them.
>
> ```
> x = rnorm(50)
> y = x + rnorm(50, mean=50, sd=.1)
> cor(x,y)
> [1] 0.995
> ```

**Observation:** Playing around with this and related examples, I see the following:

Let $x$ be vector of length $n$ randomly sampled from a normal population with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.  Let $y = x + z$ such that $z$ is a vector of length $n$ with sample mean $\bar{z}$ and sample standard deviation $s_z$.

1. Then $x$ and $y$ tend to be correlated so long as $s_z$ is reasonably low (the lower it is, the more $x$ and $y$ tend to be correlated).
2. I have also noticed that the sample mean of $z$ doesn't tend to affect the correlation between $x$ and $y$.

**Question:** Formally, why do (1) and (2) hold? (Really, I'm assuming that an understanding of (1) will automatically clarify (2)).

Comment: See our threads on [computing covariance of sums](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+sum+) and apply the definition of correlation.  That gives a rigorous algebraic approach.  Alternatively, drawing a picture of how $y$ is constructed from $x$ and $z$ will make the result immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

For illustration purpose, consider smaller vectors:

```
set.seed(101)
x = rnorm(5) # x = -0.3260365  0.5524619 -0.6749438  0.2143595  0.3107692
```

First, let's say $z$ is a vector of constant values, *i.e.*, $s_z = 0$

```
z <- rep(50, 5)
y <- x + z
```

Now `plot(x,y)` will produce a perfect straight line and `cor(x,y)` will return `1` meaning perfect correlation between $x$ and $y$. It is because given an $x$ value, we can accurately predict $y$ value ($y = x + 50$).
Again, take random values of $z$ with mean $\bar z = 50$ and standard deviation $s_z = 5$. What this means is that now $y$ depends not only on the randomness of $x$, but also randomness of $z$. Larger SD of $z$ indicates the values are more distant from the mean, $50$. So if we try to predict $y$ from $y = x + 50$, as we did before, our prediction will be a lot less accurate meaning weaker correlation. Speaking of your second question, as it should have been clear by now, SD instead of mean affects the correlation.